# replace all accent in database in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have a database table who look like this :

```
id  employe_id    PDF_ADC                               EmissionADC
1   1             1-2010_AdC - EL HAYEL.pdf             2010
3   3             3-2009_AdC - Luc.pdf                  2009
5   5             5-2010_AdC - HIRT.pdf                 2010
6   6             6-2007_AdC - Koprena.pdf              2007
7   7             7-2013-adC Alves Martins signée.pdf   2013
8   8             8-2012-adc Beautemps signée.pdf       2012
...
```

And I want to replace all `é` by `e` in the column PDF_ADC, in one SQL line if possible. I am using phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that with the function [REPLACE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_replace)

```
UPDATE yourtable SET PDF_ADC = REPLACE(PDF_ADC, 'é', 'e');
```

The syntax of replace:

> REPLACE(str,from_str,to_str)
>
> Returns the string str with all occurrences of the string from_str
>   replaced by the string to_str. REPLACE() performs a case-sensitive
>   match when searching for from_str.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
UPDATE table_name SET PDF_ADC = REPLACE(PDF_ADC, "é", "e");
```